# jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '"transaction underpriced\"

Tags: json-rpc, testnets, binance

I'm trying to deploy a BEP20 contract using Remix on Binance TestNet, but I keep getting this error:

```
creation of TToken errored: Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{\"value\":{\"code\":-32603,\"data\":{\"code\":-32000,\"message\":\"transaction underpriced\"}}}'","id":3815167297577109}
```

I increased Gwei as seen in the picture below, but still not working and when I put a value bigger than 0, I get additional error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":3815167297577252}
```

Things I noticed in Remix that I don't understand

- Why the "evm version: istanbul"
- Account address contains 0.1 TBNB not 0.1 ETH

[image]

Comment: Is your constructor payable?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It's a simple question, is your constructor marked payable?

Comment: oh sorry, no it's not.

Comment: I am facing the same error, did you resolve it? my contract gives me the same error, when i try to deploy it on BNB , if yes how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1- I assume you are sending 100 gwei thinking it is a gas price, but it's not. You don't need to mention the gas price, it will be deducted by default. If this is the case, then just don't give any value to that field.

Case 2 - In case you are trying to send 100 gwei at the time of deployment, you can't actually do that because you mentioned the constructor is not payable. For this, you have to mark your constructor `payable`.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, when I don't give any value, I still get the original error of "transaction underpriced", and i tried your answer to make it payable and add the 100 gwei, and I still get the second issue as well.

Comment: Same issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67972674/transaction-underpriced-in-bep-20-token-transaction

Comment: Thanks, so i increased the gas limit by adding 2 more zeros at the end, the error went away, but the transaction is pending for a couple of hours now!

Comment: aby luck bro? i have the same issue